# AWS EC2 check blocked incoming traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services

I built a wins server in AWS as an EC2 instance and also assigned an elastic IP. I am in conversation with someone trying to send data to the server. The port is open via inbound rules but yet it's being blocked. I can't find an easy way to view incoming traffic in AWS.  I am new to AWS. Please can someone help?

Comment: A good way to debug this type of situation is to _temporarily_ configure the Security Group to permit All Inbound traffic on all ports. If the traffic is still blocked, then the problem is likely caused by the configuration of the Amazon EC2 instance (eg nothing listening on that port).

Comment: That's a good idea but I am wary of the security implications of allowing traffic on all ports.

Answer (score 1):

The traffic in and out of a VPC can be monitored using VPC flow log.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html

The VPC flow log will also have the source IP of the system trying to connect to your VPC. The flow logs can written in Cloudwatch logs and into an S3 bucket as per you requirement. However you need to create an IAM role providing required access to write into S3 or Cloudwatch and use the IAM role while configuring the VPC flow log.

Comment: Does this also work for EC2 instances?

Comment: Yes it works for EC2 instances as well. I have an EC2 instance in private subnet connected to on premise data centre using AWS transit gateway. I can the traffic reaching the EC2 instance using AWS VPC flow log. Here is another link for your reference.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/vpc-flow-logs-log-and-view-network-traffic-flows/

Comment: This was setup successfully and I can traffic I am generating. Thank you so much for your help!!